# db2 v7R1 - Trigger INSERT New As XML Str

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Trying to create a record of changes as XML string.

The below code doesn't work, either XML cannot cast to varchar, or SQL invalid error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "QS36F"."WEBTEST1_I" 
    AFTER INSERT ON "QS36F"."WEBTEST1"
    REFERENCING  NEW AS R
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
INSERT INTO "QS36F"."WEBTEST2" ( PREVIOUS_R , NEW_R , ENTRY_DATE ) VALUES ( NULL , CAST(XMLROW(R.ID,R.ITEMNUMBER) as varchar(16355)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Also tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER "QS36F"."WEBTEST1_I" 
    AFTER INSERT ON "QS36F"."WEBTEST1"
    REFERENCING  NEW AS R
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
INSERT INTO "QS36F"."WEBTEST2" ( PREVIOUS_R , NEW_R , ENTRY_DATE ) VALUES ( NULL ,  CAST((SELECT XMLROW(R.ID, R.ITEMNUMBER) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) as varchar(16355)) , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Also tried to make the data type of WEBTEST2 as XML... No dice.

[[image]]

EDIT:
[image]

EDIT2:

[image]

I am getting

> ‬‪‬‎[‪SQL0312‬‎]‪‬‎ ‪Variable‬‎ ‪ITEMNUMBER‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪defined‬‎ ‪or‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪usable‬‎.‪

for the following query?

```
CREATE TRIGGER "QS36F"."WEBTEST1_U" 
    AFTER UPDATE ON "QS36F"."WEBTEST1"
    REFERENCING
    OLD AS o
    NEW AS r
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    INSERT INTO 
     "QS36F"."WEBTEST2" ( NEW_R , PREVIOUS_R,  ENTRY_DATE ) 
                VALUES ( (select xmlserialize(XMLROW(id as id,itemnumber as itemnumber) as varchar(16355))
                          from table ( values (r.id, r.itemnumber)) as tbl
                          ), (select xmlserialize(XMLROW(id as id,itemnumber as itemnumber) as varchar(16355))
                          from table ( values (o.id, o.itemnumber)) as tbl
                          )
                       , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                       )
          );
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  What's the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
CREATE TRIGGER "QS36F"."WEBTEST1_I" 
    AFTER INSERT ON "QS36F"."WEBTEST1"
    REFERENCING  NEW AS R
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    INSERT INTO 
     "QS36F"."WEBTEST2" ( NEW_R , ENTRY_DATE ) 
                VALUES ( (select xmlserialize(XMLROW(id as id,itemnumber as itemnumber) as varchar(16355))
                          from table ( values (r.id, r.itemnumber)) as tbl
                          )
                       , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                       )
          );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see edit of the error. For some reason null is unusable in the version of db2 I have?

Comment: Still having error though, @EDIT2. Subselect with more than one result column not valid.

Comment: ok, that's interresting...I see the same error on 7.2 with the added TS field...not sure if it's a bug or an RFE candidate.  You're going to need to have the subselect only return the XML, I've modified the answer to have the subselect return just the XML.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works. Not sure about the overhead needed for this will need to do testing. Thank you!

Comment: Can you take a look at the last update too if you can? Its the update version of the trigger

Comment: In ACS Run SQL Scripts, it usually will position the cursor to the error...which itemnum is it complaining about?  You should also have a spool file created, anything more in there?

Comment: I got it, I will post the fix in a bit but it was because i needed to define o.itemnumber as itemnumber and r.itemnumber as itemnumber, same with ids